# Difference between XmlTypeMapping and XmlMembersMapping?

Tags: .net, mono, xml-serialization

[XmlTypeMapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmltypemapping.aspx) and [XmlMembersMapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlmembersmapping.aspx) are the two child classes of [XmlMapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlmapping.aspx).

What is the difference between them?
In particular, any idea why is the Mono [code](http://git.neteril.org/mcs/plain/class/System.XML/System.Xml.Serialization/XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.cs) below is processing both separately?

```
        if (_typeMap is XmlTypeMapping)
        {
            if (_format == SerializationFormat.Literal)
                return ReadRoot ((XmlTypeMapping)_typeMap);
            else
                return ReadEncodedObject ((XmlTypeMapping)_typeMap);
        }
        else
            return ReadMessage ((XmlMembersMapping)_typeMap);
```